# Checks that a name is in the table [Lua]

Tags: lua

I'm developing a script where, it should detect if the name of a "user" is banned. That is if he is on the banned list. I can add a "name" in the list (table that stores the list of users banned), but I could not develop the function that checks if a given name is in the banned list, if it is supposed to return a print

My script split:

```
function split(str, sep)
  local arg = {}
  for i, v in string.gmatch(str, string.format("[^%s]+", sep or "%s")) do
    table.insert(arg, i)
  end
  return arg
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a collection of names, and you want to know whether or not a name is in that collection.

The simplest way to organize this is a *dictionary* where the keys are the banned users:

```
local BANNED = {
    ["alpha"] = true,
    ["gamma"] = true,
}
```

When a key is in the table, you can get the associated value out:

```
print(BANNED["alpha"]) --> true
```

When a key is not in the table, you will get `nil` out of the table:

```
print(BANNED["beta"]) -- nil
```

If the collection of names is originally organized as a *list* of names (for example, from the output of your `split` function), you can iterate over that list with a for loop, adding each name to the `BANNED` dictionary:

```
local BANNED = {}
for _, name in ipairs(names) do
    BANNED[name] = true
end
```

Comment: Now, I have a list that stores the names of "moderators."
moderator = {
        ["user1"] = true,
    ["user2"] = true,
    ["user3"] = true
        }
I want that if the user is moderator (if his name is in the list), he will be able to add other names in the list (that is, make other users moderators)

Comment: You can use the same setup to check if a name is in the collection of moderator names.

Comment: As? I could not understand

Comment: Checking whether or not a username is a moderator is exactly like checking if a user is banned. You can just have to tables, one `MODERATORS` and one `BANNED`. Whenever a user tried to change the `BANNED` set, check if they are a moderator.